# Is the product of two good pairs, itself a good pair?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Want to see whether $(X,A)\times(Y,B)=(X\times Y,A\times Y\cup X\times B)$ is a good pair whenever $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ are good pairs. Searched the text by Hatcher on Algebraic Topology, and couldn't locate so far as I searched. So trying to prove that it is **true**.

The case relevant to me now is when $A=\{x_0\}\subset X$ and $B=\{y_0\}\subset Y$ are points.

If $x_0$ is a deformation retract of, say $U$ open in $X$ and $y_0$ is a deformation retract of $V$. I see how $U\times Y$ and $X\times V$ deformation-retract to $\{x_0\}\times Y$ and $X\times\{y_0\}$ respectively.

However whether their union $U\times Y\cup X\times V$ deformation retracts to $\{x_0\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_0\}$ is still a question mark. I tried collapsing $U\times V$ to a point, and then homotoping the resulting space to $\{x_0\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_0\}$. While $U\times V$ is contractible, the quotient map collapsing $U\times V$ need not be a homotopy equivalence, because I don't know whether the pair $(U\times Y\cup X\times V,U\times V)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property or not. If it does, hurray! But if not, bad news. I am now trying to use obstruction theory, whew!

The answer to the question might turn out to be **no** which make my efforts futile! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is from [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html)

7.3.8  Let (X, A) and (Y, B) be closed coﬁbred pairs. Then the pair
(X × Y, A × Y ∪ X × B)
is also a closed coﬁbred pair.

The proof is given there. Chapter 7 of T&G is downloadable from [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/TandGCh7.pdf). The result derives from

Lillig,  J.   ‘A union theorem for coﬁbrations’.   Arch. Math. 24 
(1973) 410–415.

Actually it was a question in the first 1968 edition!  You can also find it I think in I M James, Homotopy theory and general topology (Springer) 1984.